Functions based on multiple criteria
I want to do some count functions based on multiple criteria. I have a sample dataset here:


I want to find the number of Males if BD = MCD or FSGS.
For this I tried:
=COUNTIF(Gender,"M")+COUNTIF(BD,"MCD")+COUNTIF(BD,"FSGS")
But am definitely not getting the correct answer.

I would also like to count Males if Genetic is Negative.
For this I tried:
=countif(Gender,"M")+countif(Genetic,"Positive")
But also didnt get the correct answer.


Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Use COUNTIFS  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842  The COUNTIFS function applies criteria to cells across multiple ranges and counts the number of times all criteria are met.

As eluded by @patkim, you should use COUNTIFS function to obtain the desired results.
To find males whose BDs are MCD, you can try:
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Gender],"=M",Table1[BD],"MCD")


To find males whose Genetics are negative:
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Gender],"=M",Table1[Genetic],"Negative")


Note that I have used structured reference for the table.

Here are some alternative ways to achieve using COUNTIFS():


• If the total counts are needed for multiple criteria's then using COUNTIFS()+SUM()
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Gender,"M",BD,{"MCD","FSGS"}))


• For Genetic ones:
=COUNTIFS(Gender,"M",Genetic,"Negative")


• Also if you structure your output layout like as in E8:G10 then could use the following to spill:
=COUNTIFS(Gender,E9:E10,BD,F8:G8)


And if you have access to PIVOTBY() can generate a complete report:
=PIVOTBY(Gender,BD,BD,ROWS,,1)


NOTE: I have converted the data range into a Structured References aka Tables so as whenever newer data is added the formula gets updated automatically, as well, I have used defined references with names, which you can identify the ranges.


No need for COUNTIFS.
You can use a simple SUM function. In the below formula, I assumed your data was in a Table so I could use structured references, which will automatically adjust to the size of the range:
=SUM((Table1[Gender]="M")*((Table1[BD]="FSGS")+(Table1[BD]="MCD")))

In older versions of Excel, this formula may need to be confirmed as an array formula by holding down ctrl + shift while hitting enter
